# Glow effect persists in an object even with a new material

Tags: materials, particles, light

I've encountered a problem where I have an unwanted glow in the object material - namely, the bubbles in the bathtub.

The current material I have on them is a simple diffuse with specular, and emit is set on zero. The material doesn't have any other effects. I've tried to remove all materials from the object and make a new one with the settings above, but the glow persists.

I've made the bubbles using the particles system and a custom object. I don't remember what was the material on the object used to create the particles, but it has already been deleted by this point, and the generated particles were converted to a single mesh.

Could it be that the glow was a part of the material on the particle object, and now persists even when a new material is created and assigned? Would I have to make another mesh for the bubbles to get rid of the glow, or is there some other way?

[image: rendered scene]

and here's the link to the blender file - https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0-rq_WBzqM2SHZTUnRTRDJ1ZUE

Comment: Are you sure it is the bath bubbles? Is it possible that another object or material are causing this entirely? Could possibly upload a [blend file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com) with packed textures that shows the problem?

Comment: Hello, thank you for replying! I think that the problem is with bubbles, because when I hide them entirely, the glow disappears. I've added the link in the post, hope it works. I suspect I might have messed up with the global lighting, which causes bubbles to catch too much light and reflect it back? But I'm not sure.

Comment: Well I don't know what it is, couldn't even get your scene to render. It is just stuck on "Occlusion preprocessing", but you have got too much stuff enabled in the World settings. Your scene also doesn't seem very clean or organized. There are lots of unnamed unused materials in your foam object.

Comment: It seems to be *Indirect Lighting* that is causing it, plus you have a pink shadeless material and your bathtub is an emitting material. Go figure...